# An API in WSO2 ESB only returns the first node of an JSON?

Tags: json, rest, wso2, wso2-esb

I've created a REST API in WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus.
The API calls to a mock service on SoapUI that returns a JSON with 2 nodes:

```
{
    "customer" : {
        "value1": "2312",
        "value2": "3214",
        "value3": "4214"
    },
    "msg" : "error"
}
```

The ESB should return this JSON, but it always ignores the second node ("msg") and return just the first node.

I've already changed the position, something like this, but it doesn't works:

```
{
    "msg" : "error",
    "customer" : {
        "value1": "2312",
        "value2": "3214",
        "value3": "4214"
    }
}
```

The API is really simple, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/test1" name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
  <resource methods="POST" protocol="http">
    <inSequence>
      <send>
        <endpoint key="conf:/endpoint.xml"/>
      </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence/>
    <faultSequence/>
  </resource>
</api>
```

I've already checked the mock and it's answering right to ESB

Why my API is returning only first node?

My wire logs:

```
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,343] DEBUG - wire >> "POST /CustomerHSF/retrieveCustomerHSF HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,344] DEBUG - wire >> "HOST: localhost:8283[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> "content-type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> "content-length: 100[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> "{[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> ""nomCliente": "SILVA",[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> ""tipoPessoa": "FIS",[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,345] DEBUG - wire >> ""dscEmail": "google@google.com"[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,346] DEBUG - wire >> "}[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,347]  INFO - LogMediator Starting inSequence retrieveCustomerHSF = Starting inSequence retrieveCustomerHSF
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "POST /integradorhsf/clientes/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "Host: localhost:8082[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "User-Agent: Synapse-PT-HttpComponents-NIO[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,349] DEBUG - wire << "64[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << "{[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << ""nomCliente": "SILVA",[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << ""tipoPessoa": "FIS",[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << ""dscEmail": "google@google.com.br"[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << "}[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,350] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "Content-Length: 47[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "Server: Jetty(6.1.26)[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "{[\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> ""retorno": "dados cliente",[\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> ""msg": "error"[\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,356] DEBUG - wire >> "}[\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,360]  INFO - LogMediator To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:117c7eb8-c4f2-40a4-b26d-73f64863303a, Direction: response, Starting outSequence retrieveCustomerHSF = Starting outSequence retrieveCustomerHSF, Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><retorno>dados cliente</retorno></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2016 17:04:14 GMT[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "1b[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "{"retorno":"dados cliente"}[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "0[\r][\n]"
[2016-08-03 14:04:14,369] DEBUG - wire << "[\r][\n]"
```

Comment: Please add `log4j.logger.org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire=DEBUG` to log4j.properties file and update the question with wire logs.

Comment: What is your ESB version?

Comment: Also what is the message builder/formatter configured for application/json in your axis2.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally this cannot return anything. Adding `<send/>` mediator inside `<outSequence/>` should fix the problem. You may enable wire logs and check otherwise.

Comment: I added <send/> to outsequence. The API responds, but only the first node of JSON. I tried using <respond/>, and I got the same problem.

Comment: Please try to enable wire logs as Bathiya suggested in the comment, and paste wire logs in the question as an edit.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't see Bhathiya's message. I'm gonna paste the wire logs.

Answer (score 0):

As I guess, message flow may not identify json format correctly. Please change out sequence as follows and try this out:

```
<outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
<send/>
</outSequence>
```

For complex JSON responses you can use:

```
<outSequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<property name="messageType" value="application/json/badgerfish" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
<send/>
</outSequence>
```